# Typing animation for a long text/innerhtml/child elements

Tags: html, css

I want typing animation for an html element which has very long text and sometimes child element as well. SO I want the typing animation to happen properly line by line and also if we child element, it should also get rendered using the same animation.

So I want to remove the below stylings, but that doesn't gives desired output.
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.type-writer{
  color: black;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  /*white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: black }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="type-writer">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h1>
  <span><a href="www.test.com"></a></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want Typing animation for a parent element which will long text that will wrap to many lines and it might contain  child elements as well.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. And are you using a monospaced font?

Comment: I want proper typing animation which will go line by line